# Copy range of cells from Excel

Tags: excel, autoit

I'm trying to copy some cells from Microsoft Excel to another program using AutoIt, but I can just copy one cell at a time. Is there a way to copy a group or range of cells?

My code:

```
Local $Resultcpf = Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, default, "L4")

ClipPut($Resultcpf)
$Data = ClipGet()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the range by `B3:C5` for two columns or `A1:A17` for one column and so on. The range has to be divided by **colon** ":" sign.

```
#include-once
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>

Global $sFileExcel  = @DesktopDir & '\MyExcelSheet.xlsx'
Global $sExcelRange = 'B3:C5'

Func _readExcelContent()
    Local $oExcel    = _Excel_Open()
    Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, $sFileExcel)
    Local $aData     = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, $sExcelRange, 2)
    _Excel_Close($oExcel, Default, True) ; excel will be closed
    Return $aData
EndFunc

Global $aData = _readExcelContent()
_ArrayDisplay($aData) ; this is just a preview of the read data

ClipPut(_ArrayToString($aData))
```

The result/output could be :

```
text1|
text2|text4
text3|
```

Depending on Excel content of course.

Answer (score -1):

> "*Is there a another way to copy a group of range?*"

As per [Documentation - User Defined Function Reference - `_Excel_RangeRead()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_RangeRead.htm) :

> Reads the value, formula or displayed text from a cell or range of cells of the specified workbook and worksheet

Example :

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>

Global Const $g_sFileDoc = 'C:\document.xlsx', _
             $g_sRange   = 'L:L', _; 'L1:L4'
             $g_sPrompt  = 'Press [CTRL] + [V] to paste contents of %s.'

Global       $g_oExcel   = _Excel_Open(), _
             $g_oBook    = _Excel_BookOpen($g_oExcel, $g_sFileDoc)
Global       $g_aData    = _Excel_RangeRead($g_oBook, Default, $g_oBook.ActiveSheet.Usedrange.Columns($g_sRange))
Global       $g_sData    = _ArrayToString($g_aData)

_ArrayDisplay($g_aData)
ClipPut($g_sData)
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, @ScriptName, StringFormat($g_sPrompt, $g_sRange))
```